# REST API for metadata components / types?

Tags: apex, community, api, salesforcedx, rest

I have been doing some research and I am unable to find the correct endpoint for fetching Metadata Types & Components.

Somehow, in workbench they are able to fetch this information and it can be found by logging in to workbench -> info -> Metadata Types & Components.

The REST explorer in workbench does not have an endpoint that would lead me to this data it seems, so I am hoping someone here would have a better knowledge of this than me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

These are the "describe" calls. There's two basic calls.

## Describe Global

```
/services/data/v45.0/sobjects/
```

Lists all types of objects you have access to, and various properties (such as user permissions and certain REST URLs).

## Describe sObject

```
/services/data/v45.0/sobjects/[ObjectName]/describe
```

Describes fields, record types, related children, and other related information for an object.

Other calls are also available. Please read the [REST documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/) for more details.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I'm not too worried about fetching data for a specific object as I can find the endpoints for those. The data that I am really interested in is the metadata  components, if confused, by following steps mentioned above with workbench you can see what I am interested in. The data that I am interested in can be found under "flow" in workbench (follow the steps, select flow) and it contains ids of processes.